# How to copy file from UNC-share to local system?

Tags: c#, .net, unc, windows-identity

I'm stuck with this question.

I have UNC share, I know account details, which has fullaccess, but it doesn't have access to my local system.
I can get access to remote UNC with :

```
var token = default(IntPtr);
var context = default(WindowsImpersonationContext);
LogonUser(_config.Username, _config.Domain, _config.Password, 2, 0, out token);
context = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(token);

//TODO :: System.IO operations
File.Copy("remote-unc-path","local-path",true); // Exception : Access is denied.

context.Undo();
CloseHandle(token);
```

But, I can't access my local system during Impersonation, because account doesn't have access to it.

How to copy file in this situation? Do i need to use something like buffer and turn on/off Impersonation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have to do is to read all the bytes and then write them:

```
    var token = default(IntPtr);
    using (var context = default(WindowsImpersonationContext))
    {
       LogonUser(_config.Username, _config.Domain, _config.Password, 2, 0, out token);
       context = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(token);
       var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("remote-unc-path");
       context.Undo();
       CloseHandle(token);
       File.WriteAllBytes("local-path", bytes);
    }
```

Comment: But, files are huge... ~200Mb - ~1Gb.. also, this is part of system, which can have several "unc-file-storages". It will copy files in different threads... I really don't want to ReadALL for each file.. It will eat all memory

Comment: I've found a solution... Its name is WNetUseConnection

Comment: @Oskar - This used to work like a charm for me using Windows Server 2003 / IIS6.x but with Windows Server 2008 / IIS 7.5 it will only work (at least as far as I can tell) if the user has a "Local" user account on the system I'm trying to connect to.  So yeah, desperately seeing a non-Administrator-account answer to this one as well. Stupid Windows security. :-\